# number rounded down in select statement with equation SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I do

select 18000*13/100000

it returns 2

when it should return 2.34

How do I make it return the correct number?

thanks

Comment: `select 18000.0*13/100000`

Comment: Yeah you need to add a decimal point in there somewhere otherwise SQL will assume you want the result back as an integer.

Comment: SQL server uses integer math that is, when working with whole numbers it will return only whole numbers, to get decimals you can use implicit casting such as is done by adding .0 to any number, or you can explicitly cast an integer to a numeric value with set decimals.  using float you may get unexpected rounding errors due to the nature of FLOAT so depending on the context of the math, float may not be what your after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 18000*13/100000.0
```

Use a `float` either in numerator or denominator to get a float.

Answer (score 1):

Use a decimal point to avoid integer division:

```
select 18000.0*13/100000
```

You can also `CAST()` as `DECIMAL` or `FLOAT` a field, but I like to just use `mycol *1.0`